# my YUY2 output does not work with Video Renderer filter

Tags: directshow

I have a basic avstream driver (based on the avshws sample).

When testing the YUY2 output I get different results based on which renderer I use:

- Video Renderer: blank image
- VMR-7: scrambled image (due to the renderer using a buffer with a larger stride)
- VMR-9: perfect render

I dont know why the basic video renderer (used by amcap) wont work. I have examined the graph of a webcam outputting the same format and I cannot see any difference apart from the renderer output.

Comment: Perhaps bad-formed media type. You have not posted relevant details.

Comment: Can you elaborate please?

Comment: By "You have not posted relevant details." I mean that you should add to the post what you have found during your graph examination: "same format" and "any difference" in particular. Otherwise you ask us to shoot in the dark.

Comment: Unmodified avshws code works with YUY2 and Video Renderer. It stopped working after I removed the scatter/gather and DMA stuff. I changed it so that the pin process dispatch just returns STATUS_PENDING, and when the fake hardware timer fires it fills out a pending video buffer and restarts processing (KsPinGetLeadingEdgeStreamPointer, copy memory, KsStreamPointerUnlock(eject=true), KsPinAttemptProcessing). This works in RGB24 mode but not YUY2...

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're writing your own filter based on [avshws](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowshardware/AVSHwS-AVStream-Simulated-7953991d). I'm not familiar with this particular sample but generally you need to ensure two things:

- Make sure your filter checks any media types proposed are acceptable. In the DirectShow baseclasses the video renderer calls the output pin [IPin::QueryAccept](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd390428(v=vs.85).aspx) which calls whichever base class member you're using e.g. [CBasePin.CheckMediaType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd368693(v=vs.85).aspx) or [CTransformFilter.CheckTransform](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/dd388133(v=vs.85).aspx)
- Make sure you call [IMediaSample::GetMediaType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/dd407009(v=vs.85).aspx) on every output sample and respond appropriately e.g. calling [CTransformFilter.SetMediaType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd388154(v=vs.85).aspx)  and changing the format/stride of your output. It's too late to negotiate at this point - you've accepted the change already and if you really can't continue you have to abort streaming, return an error HRESULT and [notify](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms901457.aspx) EC_ERRORABORT or EC_ERRORABORTEX. Unless it's buggy the downstream filter should have called your output pin's QueryAccept and received S_OK before it sends a sample with a media type change attached (I've seen occasional filters that add duplicate media types to the first sample without asking).

See [Handling Format Changes from the Video Renderer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd388901(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the problem. I was missing one line to update the remaining bytes in the stream pointer structure:

Leading->OffsetOut.Remaining = 0;

This caused certain filters to drop my samples (AVI/MJPEG Decompressor, Dump) which meant that certain graph configurations would simply not render anything.